# $m \times n$ matrix gives rise to a well-defined map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

As the title suggests, how do I see that an $m \times n$ matrix gives rise to a well-defined map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: Consider the map $\mathbf{x}\mapsto A\mathbf{x}$. In fact, every linear map has its corresponding matrix and vice versa.

Comment: Not until you fix a basis. Then, yes.

Comment: True, although I would argue that $\mathbb{R}^n$ conventionally comes with an implicit Cartesian basis unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map induced by a matrix $M \in \mathrm M _{m \times n}(\mathbb R)$ (or any field, for that matter) is defined by matrix multiplication. Given a vector $v \in \mathbb R ^n$ (i.e. an $n \times 1$ vector), its image is $Mv$ (an $m \times 1$ vector). In other notation:

$$
\begin{align}
\phi_M : \mathbb R ^n &\to \mathbb R ^m \\
v &\mapsto Mv
\end{align}
$$

Since matrix multiplication is well-defined, we have the map we are looking for.

Comment: I take your field and raise you a ring.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thank you (:  May I be so bold as to drop multiplicative associativity?

Comment: well, that I don't know, I mean, certainly $A(BC)=(AB)C$ for matrix multiplication built with elements of a ring. Is there a way to build matrix multiplication over an object with less structure such that we lose associativity? That seems possible, but, I don't have an answer handy. On the other hand, matrix multiplication can represent operations which are not associative, for example, $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is well-known to fail associativity as measured by the Jacobi identity. Interesting question.